# C# Deserialization automatically deserialize a String as a byte array to attribute via custom code?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a class with a byte array as an attribute as binary

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="hexBinary")]
    public byte[] aValue {
        get {
            return this.aValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.aValueField= value;
        }
    }
```

The data itself...for aValue...has a String inside in the XML file I am attempting to deserialize in certain files
.

To deserialize I do this:

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
using (Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
{
     config = (Data)xml.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

The problem is, the data in the XML file, it has a String there not a byte[] (but other files do have a valid byte[] too).  I cannot change the input file data nor can I change the attribute to a String, it has to be a byte[] for other files processed.  Is there a way to do a custom conversion during this deserialization process somehow during via code for just this field, if the input is a String, to do a Custom Conversion to byte[] using logic?  That way it doesn't exception and not get the class.

Comment: So sometimes it's binary, sometimes it's a string? Can you show an example of both in an edit?

Comment: It would be something like "0000000000000000" or "Hello!" (Hello! needs to be converted into binary first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can differentiate between the string and the byte[] in code, you can add another property to handle the serialization, and make aValue XmlIgnore so it won't be deserialized but it will still get set inside bValue set.

```
private string bValueField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public byte[] aValue { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("aValue")]
public string bValue
{
    get
    {
        return bValueField;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Contains("string identifier here")) // i.e. it's not a byte[]
        {
            aValue = new byte[] { };
            bValueField = value;
        }
        else // it's a byte[]
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? "")))
            {
                aValue = (byte[])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                bValueField = "not a string";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a sort of like "pre-parser" on a special attribute, so I could keep the class alone, but this seems like a satisfactory answer if nothing turns up in 24 hours.